# Remove Duplicates from array of objects but keep empty string value objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have this function which works pretty well, removes duplicate of emails.

```
contacts.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.email===v.email))===i);
```

But it seems to remove objects with empty email strings but I want to keep those objects. Just emails that match emails should be removed

```
var arr = [
  {
    name: '1',
    city: 'lagos',
    email: 'second@gmail.com',
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    city: 'abuja',
    email: 'second@gmail.com',
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    city: 'ibadan',
    email: '',
  },
  {
    name: '4',
    city: 'kano',
    email: '',
  },
];
```

From the array above, I want to removes duplicate from 1 and 2 while keeping 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lodash's [`_.uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) to dedupe the array. In the predicate function, return the email or a [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) for empty strings, since a symbol is always unique:

```js
const arr = [{"name":"1","city":"lagos","email":"second@gmail.com"},{"name":"2","city":"abuja","email":"second@gmail.com"},{"name":"3","city":"ibadan","email":""},{"name":"4","city":"kano","email":""}];

const result = _.uniqBy(arr, o => o.email || Symbol());

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is asking *'I want to keep 3 and 4 but delete 1 and 2'*

Comment: Yea it's a bit ambiguous, but his code says otherwise.  I figure that he wants to dedupe an array by email, but keep users without emails.

Comment: Brilliant this is what I wanted. Removes duplicate from 1 and 2 while keeping 2 and 4. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Why not put in a special case for the email being ""?

Change

```
contacts.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.email===v.email))===i);
```

to

```
contacts.filter((v,i,a)=>
    v.email==="" || 
    a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.email===v.email))===i
);
```

That way, you keep your original function working the way it was, and just add the ability to keep the `email:""` cases also.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name: '1',
    city: 'lagos',
    email: 'second@gmail.com',
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    city: 'abuja',
    email: 'second@gmail.com',
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    city: 'ibadan',
    email: '',
  },
  {
    name: '4',
    city: 'kano',
    email: '',
  },
];


const getUniqueEmails = (arr) => {
     const emptyEmailObjects = arr.filter(v => v.email === '');
     const uniqueObjects = arr.filter((v, i, a) => v.email !== 
     '' && i === a.findIndex(t => t.email === v.email));
     return [...uniqueObjects, ...emptyEmailObjects];
   };  
   
   
 console.log(getUniqueEmails(arr))
```

Add this helper function

```
   const getUniqueEmails = (arr) => {
     const emptyEmailObjects = arr.filter(v => v.email === '');
     const uniqueObjects = arr.filter((v, i, a) => v.email !== 
     '' && i === a.findIndex(t => t.email === v.email));
     return [...uniqueObjects, ...emptyEmailObjects];
   };
```

Comment: The function provided is using a variable 'arr' instead of the parameter 'contacts', and is also not correctly filtering out duplicates while keeping empty email string objects

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @HaseebMir i have changed the function , and  it also keep the email:" " which is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your original function and not use additional packages you can just check the email length as well in your filter function:

```
arr.filter((v, i, a) => !v.email.length || a.findIndex(v2 => (v2.email === v.email)) === i);
```